# How do I give a person a role with buttons in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I'm very new to discord.js and javascript in general, and I'm trying to make something similar to reaction roles, but with buttons, so if you click the button with the role on you, it will remove it, and add it if you don't have the role, but the problem that I'm getting is that the member's roles is "undefined", and I've seen no articles about it.

Here's the code:

````
Client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
  if (!interaction.id == "ButtonRoles") return
  const users = interaction.user.id
  const User2 = interaction.options.getMember(users)
  
  console.log(User2.roles)
  if (User2.roles.has("915742313525952523")) {
    interaction.reply({ content: 'Successfully added role!', ephemeral: true })
  User2.roles.add("915742313525952523")
  }
  else {
  interaction.reply({ content: 'Successfully removed role!', ephemeral: true })
  User2.roles.remove("915742313525952523")
  }
    
});

Client.on("message", (message) => {
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "-createreactionrole") {
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   
    const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('ButtonRoles')
    .setLabel('Announcement Pings')
    .setStyle('SUCCESS')
 .setEmoji(""),
);   
 message.channel.send({ content: 'Please press the button for the role that you would like.', components: [row] })
 }
});```
````

Comment: You might be missing an intent

Comment: @Laif What kind of intent am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to make some changes to your code to make it work properly, I have notated as such below:

As for intents your code should look like this at minimal:

```js
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES']
})
```

```js
Client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const buttonID = interaction.customId;
        if (buttonID === 'ButtonRoles') { // get button by customId set below
            const member = interaction.member; // get member from the interaction - person who clicked the button

            console.log(member.roles.cache);

            if (member.roles.cache.has('915742313525952523')) { // if they already have the role
                member.roles.remove('915742313525952523'); // remove it
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: 'Successfully removed role!',
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            } else { // if they don't have the role
                member.roles.add('915742313525952523'); // add it
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: 'Successfully added role!',
                    ephemeral: true
                })
            }
        }
    }
});

Client.on("messageCreate", async message => { // corrected your event listener should be messageCreate not message as message is deprecated
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "-createreactionrole") {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('ButtonRoles')
                .setLabel('Announcement Pings')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                .setEmoji(""),
            );
        message.channel.send({
            content: 'Please press the button for the role that you would like.',
            components: [row]
        })
    }
});
```